# how to return a filepath and use it in another method?

Tags: java

I wonder if it is possible to return a filepath from JFileChooser and then use the path in another method?

I have tried so many different things without luck. It seems so basic, but i just can't figure it out.

Any one want to explain what to do?

my code is here:

```
public void run()
{

    //runs the program and adds it to the gui grid
    fieldObject.fromFile(selectedFile); //this is where i want to load the file to
    try {
          Solve(fieldObject, 0, 0);
        }
        catch (SolvedException e) {}
        System.out.println("Please select a file in the load menu first");

}



//The FileChooser method
static void FileChooser()
{
    JButton Chooser = new JButton();

    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt", "txt"));
    fc.setDialogTitle("Choose a txt file");
    if (fc.showOpenDialog(Chooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {

        File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();

    }
    else if (fc.showOpenDialog(Chooser) == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
    {
        System.out.println("canceled");
    }
    return selectedFile;
}
```

Comment: i know i have to define the .getabsolutepath but i already tried this.

Comment: String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score 1):

You broken `FileChooser()` method fixed with return type `String`:

```
static String FileChooser() {
    JButton Chooser = new JButton();
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt", "txt"));
    fc.setDialogTitle("Choose a txt file");
    switch (fc.showOpenDialog(Chooser)) {
    case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
        return fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    default:
        System.out.println("canceled");
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can use it as:

```
String file = FileChooser();
```

**EDIT**

You want to save the result in a field to be used in the second button click:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String path;

    public MyClass() {
        JButton b = new JButton("Button 1");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                path = FileChooser();
            }
        });
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //User 'path' variable here
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        });
    }

    static String FileChooser() {
        JButton Chooser = new JButton();
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt", "txt"));
        fc.setDialogTitle("Choose a txt file");
        switch (fc.showOpenDialog(Chooser)) {
        case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
            return fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        default:
            System.out.println("canceled");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>P.S. - I'd recommend use naming conventions. E.g. - `fileChooser()` instead of `FileChooser()`.</sub>

Comment: nice! it was what i wanted :)
but what name is the file returned as? when i want to load the file with the run method?

Comment: Returned values don't have name. You can, however, assign them to named variables. e.g. in you `main` method, you do `String file = FileChooser();` and the variable file will contain the path of the file

Comment: okay, i'm thinking return as a kind of save command? is that right?

Comment: when i press my run button after loading my file, the FileChooser pop up again.

Comment: Post the rest of your code and explain what you're trying to do

Comment: my code is way to big for you to read atm.

but let's say i have 2 buttons. button 1 launches filechooser and you select a file, button 2 then reads the file that you selected in filechooser.

so i want the choosen file to be "saved" so i can use it later on when i press button 2.

Comment: You can store the result of first button press in a field and then, when you press the second button, you can read this variable to access the path previously selected.